# How do I increase memory limit (contiguous as well as overall) in Matlab r2012b?

Tags: windows, matlab, out-of-memory

I am using Matlab r2012b on win7 32-bit with 4GB RAM.
However, the memory limit on Matlab process is pretty low. On *memory* command, I am getting the following output:

```
Maximum possible array:    385 MB (4.038e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1281 MB (1.343e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    421 MB (4.413e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3496 MB (3.666e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

I need to increase the limit to as much as possible.

System: Windows 7 32 bit
RAM: 4 GB
Matlab: r2012b

Comment: Side note: Maybe you can also work on your operation? [What do you require the memory for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The big quick win is using the `3gb switch` as described in the answer. However, if you want to add serious amounts of memory your best option is really going for a 64bit version of Matlab.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 1):

For general guidance with memory management in MATLAB, see [this MathWorks article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html). Some specific suggestions follow.

Set the [`/3GB` switch in the boot.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to increase the memory available to MATLAB. Or [set it with a properties dialog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124810%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) if you are averse to text editors. This is mentioned in [this section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html#brh72ex-67) of the above MathWorks page.

Also use [`pack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pack.html) to increase the `Maximum possible array` by compacting the memory. The 32-bit MATLAB memory needs blocks of contiguous free memory, which  is where this first value comes from. The `pack` command saves all the variables, clears the workspace, and reloads them so that they are contiguous in memory.

More on overall memory, try disabling the virtual machine, closing programs, stopping unnecessary Windows services.  No easy answer for this part.